# How would you calculate the sum of interior angles from a SVG path?

Tags: math, svg

For example, a path like the one below:

```
<path d="M 35 50 L 35 35 L 90 90 z" fill="goldenrod"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you contour is closed (z-command) and it is simple polygon, then [sum of interior angle](http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/interior-angles-polygons.html)s is

```
SA = 180 * (n - 2)
```

where n is the number of vertices.

Here are 3 vertices, so `SA = 180`

(It works also for concave polygons, but not for self-intesecting ones (they are 'not simple'))

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't even think about self-intersecting ones. Is there a simple way to check if the path is self-intersecting?

Comment: For small number of segments (dozens) it is simpler to check all segment-segment intersection (quadratic complexity), for hundreds and thousands it would better to use sweep line algorithm (O(nlogn))

Comment: Thanks, I'm also trying to come up with a simpler way to check if a polygon is concave/convex besides just looking at the angles. You have any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you can calculate cross-product of neighbor edges in order and check for their signs. For convex polygon all cross-product signs are the same (or positive, or negative, depending on walk direction)

Answer (score 0):

MBo's answer is good, but if you want to explicitly calculate the angles you can use the dot product. For two vector `A = (Ax,Ay), B=(Bx,By)` the dot product is given by `A.B = Ax*Bx+Ay*By`. If the length of A is `|A|=sqrt(Ax*Ax+Ay*Ay)` then angle between the vectors has the relationship `A . B = |A| |B| cos(angle)`. So the angle is given by

```
acos( A . B / ( |A| |B| )
```

Assume the element in you svg code has an explicit id.

```
<svg id="picture" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="400" height="300">
<path id="poly" d="M 35 50 L 35 35 L 90 90 z" fill="goldenrod"/>
</svg>
```

You can find the angles using:

```
poly = document.getElementById("poly"); // get the svg element
// get the parts of the d attribute and split on space.
parts = poly.getAttribute("d").split(/\s+/); 
x=[],y=[]; // Arrays to hold x,y coords
j=0;
// loop through parts of svg, extract x,y coords
for(i=0;i<parts.length-1;i+=3) {
    x[j]=parts[i+1];
    y[j]=parts[i+2];
    ++j;    
}
sum=0; // variable to hold the sum
for(var i=0;i<x.length;++i) {   // loop through each vertex
   prev = i >0 ? i-1 : x.length-1;  // get previous index
   next = (i+1) % x.length;         // get next index  

   Ax = x[next] - x[i]; Ay = y[next] - y[i]; // vector A
   Bx = x[prev] - x[i]; By = y[prev] - y[i]; // Vector B
   dot = Ax * Bx + Ay * By;  // dot product
   lenA = Math.sqrt(Ax*Ax + Ay*Ay); // Length of A
   lenB = Math.sqrt(Bx*Bx + By*By); // Or use Math.hypot
   angle = Math.acos( dot / (lenA * lenB)); // find angle using 
   sum+=angle; // find sum
}
// print the sum (using degrees)
console.log(180 * sum / Math.PI);
```

Note the result is 179.99999999999997 close to that from MBo.

There is a small bug in the above code as it does not work with concave polygons. This can be fixed using a 2D version of the cross product, to find if the angle is reflex. At the end of the loop add:

```
   cross = Ax * By - Ay * Bx;
   if(cross > 0)
       sum+=angle;
   else
     sum += Math.PI*2 - angle;
```